# How to auto-refresh a web page, even if server returned an error?

Tags: javascript, html, http, http-headers

I have an HTML+JS web page, which uses `http-equiv="refresh"` to auto-refresh itself every few seconds. However, sometimes the server returns a 502 "bad gateway" error, so the HTML code is not loaded to the client and thus this auto-refresh does not work any more. However, mnanually refresing the page via F5 in the browser does correctly reload the page.

Now I would like to make this page a bit more robust by allowing itself to refresh, even after a 502 error has been returned. So in other words, the client should try to reload the HTML page after X seconds, in any case.

Is there any way to achieve this kind of auto-refreshing, even if the server does return an error instead of the real HTML page?

Comment: Use `window.setInterval()` instead?

Comment: @wazz Well, but what do I reload within `setInterval()`? I cannot reload the whole page.

Comment: Yes, the page. Every single part of your question suggests you want to reload the page.

Comment: @wazz If I realod the whole page via JS as you suggested, and the server returns the 502 error, then again the page itself is not being refreshed, so again that JS code is not being called. Same problem as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. For the records:

The page content (everything within the `<body>` tags) has been moved into another page, which is displayed on the main page (wrapper) via an iframe. That wrapper page itself does the reloading via JS.